# Wifi wont connect

Tags: system-installation, wifi

Running from installation off flash drive only.  Wifi wont connect though it sees my signal.  What adjustments do I need to make use my wifi?

Comment: Please add more details of your system, such as wifi driver.

Comment: Indeed we need more detail to help you, that it is your model of wifi card. If you have install elementary OS you can send us the output of this command : `lshw -C network` by edit your message.